# Javascript - Store input in object, then to array, then display on page

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm completing a task right now where I'm required to store input values from a user into an object variable, and then add the object to an array, do this continously until user leaves input boxes blank, then the array is displayed. This is what I have so far:

```
function init() {
    var vPerson1 = {};
    var people = [];
    var dogname = "";
    var toysamt = "";
    dogname = prompt("Please enter dog name");
    toysamt = prompt("Please enter toys amount");
    while (dogname != "" && toysamt != "") {
        vPerson1[dogname] = dogname;
        vPerson1[toysamt] = toysamt;
        people.push(vPerson1);
        dogname = prompt("Please enter dog name");
        toysamt = prompt("Please enter toys amount");
}

var vIndex = 0;
var outputpeople = "";
for (vIndex = 0; vIndex < people.length; vIndex++) {
outputpeople = outputpeople + people[vIndex] + "<br />";
document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = outputpeople;
}

}

window.onload = init;
```

Running this code:

I enter "jeff" and "3" for first two input boxes, and then "bob" and "6" for second set of input boxes, I then leave the next 2 textboxes blank to end the loop. What is displayed on the page is this:

[object Object]

[object Object]

The output is meant to be something like:

Dog 1 Name: ... No. of toys: ...

Dog 2 ...

I also need a function that will calculate the total amount of toys if anyone can help with that. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: I think it's displayed only the last people from array :)

Comment: Put `var vPerson1 = {}` into the while loop.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut - I feel the same. Just want to hear it from the OP

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output ? Please add it in the question.

Comment: I added more information to the question at the bottom, hope that helps. Feel free to completely reinvent the code for the solution, my current code is just fumbled code trying to get the right output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```js
function init() {
        var people = [];
        var dogname = prompt("Please enter dog name");
        var toysamt = prompt("Please enter toys amount");
        while (dogname != "" && toysamt != "") {
            /* Assuming that you need "dogname" as the key 
             * and not the user input value as key */
            people.push({dogname, toysamt});
            dogname = prompt("Please enter dog name");
            toysamt = prompt("Please enter toys amount");
        }

        var toys = 0;
        /* You can prepare the output html using Array.reduce function */ 
        document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = people.reduce((a,c, i) => {
           a += "Dog " + (i+1) + " Name:" + c.dogname + ", No. of toys:" + c.toysamt + "<br/>";
           toys += parseInt(c.toysamt);
           return a;    
        }, "");
        document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML += "Total Number of toys: " + toys;
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="msg1"></div>
```